# Анимирование одиночного компонента vue через transition

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

При попытке использовать компонент vue - transition, позволяющим анимировать появление и исчезновение элемента, столкнулся с тем, что редактор (Web Storm) отказывается воспринимать данный компонент, описывая это тем, что компонент transition не существует (Unknown  html tag transition).

Код:

```
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Переключить
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})


.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active до версии 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Comment: Ну и в чем вопрос?

Comment: Редактор не  воспринимает тег transition. Не понимаю почему, пример взят с оф. документации